# Special chararacters in textile

Tags: pandoc, textile

The following HTML should be converted to textile:

```
**** Ressourcen schonen, weniger drucken - Think before you print! ****
```

As far as I can see, this is valid HTML.

Converting this to Textile with pandoc via

```
pandoc -f html -t textile filename.html
```

the output for this piece is encoded like this:

```
&#42;&#42;&#42;&#42; Ressourcen schonen, weniger drucken - Think before you print! &#42;&#42;&#42;&#42;
```

This looks to be valid Textile, according to [some sites](http://txstyle.org/doc/42/special-characters) which happily decode it. [Other sites](http://textile.sitemonks.com/) however, complain that this is not valid:

```
Your text appears to contain something that shouldn’t be pasted into our textile form.
```

Also, pandoc reverse transformation of the output in Textile format returns this:

```
&amp;#42;&amp;#42;&amp;#42;&amp;#42; Ressourcen schonen, weniger drucken - Think before you print! &amp;#42;&amp;#42;&amp;#42;&amp;#42;
```

Now the ampersands themselves are encoded, and it seems, pandoc doesn't see the output it generated itself to be valid input.

Is there a way around this? Is this really valid Textile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is valid Textile; according to the [RedCloth 4 spec](http://redcloth.org/textile/html-integration-and-escapement/#inline-html), inline HTML is allowed, and the dingus confirms it.

Pandoc converts the `*` to an entity when writing textile to ensure that literal asterisks don't accidentally trigger emphasis.

You've uncovered a bug in the pandoc textile reader, which should interpret `&#42;` as a literal asterisk character.  This should be reported on the [pandoc bug tracker](http://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues).

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what RedCloth 4 Spec has to do with Pandoc or the Textile format, but I understand that HTML is valid in Textile via your link. After reading on how to report a bug, I might do it if I have alot of free time on my hands (they're not making it easy). However, you answered my question.

Comment: That's okay, I already fixed the problem with the textile reader.